A question about the transitive subgroups of $S_4$
I'm trying to show that any transitive subgroup $H$ of $S_4$ is conjugated to one of the following subgroups: $V_4=\langle (12)(34),(13)(24)\rangle$, $C_4=\langle (1234)\rangle$, $D_4$, $A_4$ or $S_4$ itself.
Where, clearly we say that $H$ is transitive if it acts transitively on the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$.
I solved all the cases except for $|H|=4$, for which we should get that either $H=V_4$, or $H=C_4$. To this extent, following an exercise of Rotman "An Introduction to the Theory of Groups", I considered the value $m=[H:H\cap V_4]$, which by the Second Isomorphism Theorem must be a divisor of $6$. So, by this constraint, we distinguish two cases: either $|H\cap V_4|=4$ (and in this case we get $H=V_4$), or $|H\cap V_4|=2$, and in this case we have that $H\cap V_4=\langle (ab)(cd)\rangle$ for some distinct $a,b,c,d\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. Now, I can see that any $\sigma\in H\setminus V_4$ has order $2$ or $4$, and satisfies $\sigma^2\in V_4$, but at this point I'm stuck.
I would appreciate it if anyone had an idea of how to conclude the argument.

This might help.

Thank you, I saw that argument, but I don't see why should it give the thesis. Also, it is not proved why $\sigma^2$ is non-trivial. I agree with the fact that if $\sigma^2=(ab)(cd)=:\theta$, then $\sigma^4=id$ and hence $\theta\sigma\theta=\sigma^{-1}$, but why should this give that $H=C_4$?

Suppose $\sigma^2 = id$. What possibilities are there for $\sigma^2$? Then, knowing that $|H| = 4$ and that we already know that $(ab)(cd) \in H$, which of those possibilities could actually be in $H$ without causing it to be too large?
